# Post to Facebook group without being an dministrator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to automate my own posts to private Facebook groups that I joined and can post using the website. Using the api it seems impossible.I read the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/feed and multiple SO posts and this is the information I gathered:

- You need `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` authorizations (I added them to the token, and also tried with all possible authorizations)
- It seems you need approval from Facebook but I'm currently developing the application It's not ready to be approved yet I want to finish it before
- It works If I'm an administrator of the group. If it is not the case then I get a 200 error.

Is there a way to publish to groups in this situation ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: No, there is no other way.

Comment: So I need approval from facebook for an app that does not exist yet ? It sounds a little absurd no ?

Comment: This is not about approval. There is no way for you to post to a closed group if you are not an admin of that group.

Comment: So the only solution is to reverse engineer the network calls made by the website and/or make a bot using phantomjs and friends ?

Comment: Only that is against Facebook ToS as well.

Comment: just ask the admin to add you as group manager if you really want to do this. it´s a good thing that random group members can´t just spam groups.

Comment: That means I would have too much rights (accept and reject members)